# SmartGwt error with tree

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have got problem with my smartgwt when its all fine working when I am using smartgwt 2.2 but when I am using smartgwt 4.0b (night build) I have got error:

```
00:00:48,253 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.Tree::create()([]): null   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.Tree.create(Tree.java)  at com.smartgwt.client.core.BaseClass.getOrCreateJsObj(BaseClass.java:120)  at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.TreeGrid.setData(TreeGrid.java:2393)    at pl.fizzycomp.departments.gwt.client.DepartmentsMainView.setModelData(DepartmentsMainView.java:175)   at com.test.departments.gwt.client.DepartmentsMainPresenter.setDepartments(DepartmentsMainPresenter.java:208)   at com.test.gwt.client.DepartmentsApp$2.onSuccess(DepartmentsApp.java:80)   at com.test.gwt.client.DepartmentsApp$2.onSuccess(DepartmentsApp.java:1)
```

I dont know what is wrong this is my code in DepartmentsMainView:

```
tree = new Tree();
tree.setModelType(TreeModelType.PARENT);
tree.setNameProperty(DepartmentTreeNode.NAME_FIELD);
tree.setParentIdField(DepartmentTreeNode.PARENT_ID_FIELD);
tree.setIdField(DepartmentTreeNode.ID_FIELD);


tree.setData(nodes.toArray(new DepartmentTreeNode[nodes.size()]));          

grid.setData(tree);
```

and my DepartmentTreeNode:

```
public class DepartmentTreeNode extends TreeNode implements IDepartmentTreeNode {
    public static final String ID_FIELD = "idField";
    public static final String NAME_FIELD = "nameField";
    public static final String CODE_FIELD = "codeField";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION_FIELD = "descriptionField";
    public static final String PARENT_ID_FIELD = "parentId";
    public static final String VERSION_FIELD = "versionField";

    public DepartmentTreeNode(DepartmentDto dto) {
        setTitle(dto.getName());

        setAttribute(ID_FIELD, dto.getId());
        setAttribute(PARENT_ID_FIELD, dto.getParentId());
        setDepartmentName(dto.getName());
        setAttribute(CODE_FIELD, dto.getCode());
        setAttribute(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, dto.getDescription());
        setAttribute(VERSION_FIELD, dto.getVersion());
    }
```

So its look like everything fine I am checking object DepartmentTreeNode by sysout ant its good. So what's wrong?

---

In smart gwt console Resoult i heve got only info:

```
16:03:28.801:INFO:Log:initialized
16:03:28.848:WARN:Log:NOTE: Firebug is enabled. Firebug greatly slows the performance of applications that make heavy use of JavaScript. Isomorphic highly recommends Firebug for troubleshooting, but Firebug and other development tools should be disabled when assessing the real-world performance of SmartClient applications.
16:03:31.717:WARN:Log:New Class ID: 'DataView' collides with ID of existing object with value 'function DataView() {
    [native code]
}'.  Existing object will be replaced.
This conflict would be avoided by disabling ISC Simple Names mode.  See documentation for further information.
16:03:32.782:INFO:Log:isc.Page is loaded
```

I also clean my project mvn clean install and I don't think that is problem with nightly builds. Because if I am using smartgwt2.5 I have got this error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nightly build errors really belong on the SmartGWT forum.  It may quite likely be a bug.

The other thing you should make sure is that your project is clean of old generated code.  To be certain, delete any old generated code in your war directory.

And finally, use the SmartGWT console:  http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Debugging.html - it sometimes makes these cryptic errors more clear